# Sum of degrees of vertices = sum of number of vertices with the same degree

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite tree. For each $n \in \Bbb N$ let $\alpha_n$ >denote the number of vertices with degree $n$. Show that
>
> $$(i) \sum_{n\ge1}n*\alpha_n = \sum_{a\in V}deg_G(a)$$
>   $$(ii) \sum_{n\ge 0} \alpha_n = |V| $$

As for (i) this is quite evident, but I do not know how to mathematicaly prove this statement. We know that $\sum_{a\in V}deg_G(a) = 2|E|$ by the handshake lemma.

Also, I though of defining $\alpha_n$ like this: $|\{v \in V: deg_G(v) = n \} |$ and proving (i) by induction on $|V|$ but for the inductive step I have an extra vertex whose degree is unknown. So maybe this is not the right approach. My question here is: How do I proceed? Am I even in the right track?

For (ii) this is also very clear. In words the sum could be expressed as "sum of all the number of vertices with degree 0" + "sum of all the number of vertices with degree 1" +... so eventually all of the vertices are counted, and hence the sum is |V|. My question here is: How can I articulate this mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part note that $n \cdot a_n$ stands for the number of edges adjacent to the vertices of degree $n$. Similarly as in the Handshake Lemma you count edge twice (from both endpoints), so

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} n \cdot a_n = 2e(G) = \sum_{a \in V(G)} deg(a)$$

For the second one your reasoning is OK. To prove it more rigorously split the vertex set in subsets where $V_n$ contains the vertices of degree $n$. Then obviously these subsets are disjoint and we have:

$$|V| = \sum_{n \ge 0} |V_n| =\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n$$